# Bloqueo parcial de UI de Progress Dialog

Tags: android

Necesitaba saber si hay alguna forma de no bloquear toda la UI cuando hago aparecer un Progress Dialog,ya que en mi app tengo un un footer el cual quiero que este activo pero el resto de la UI en segundo plano.
Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Prueba a añadir el progress en un hilo nuevo. De todos modos, pública el código de la activity para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que no quieres el Progress Dialog este en el mismo plano que el footer. Creo que aquí sería buena idea agregar una imagen de lo que deseas para no estar adivinando =).

Comment: No es posible pasar solo una parte de la pantalla a segundo plano. Tus alternativas serían: 1. Incorporar el Footer en el dialog 2. Agregar un spinner (sin dialog) de manera manual